# Modulus.io and Meteor - Deploy to a subdomain

Tags: meteor, modulus.io

I have an app in development that I've deployed to Galaxy and it works great! There are two versions of the site, each in different languages. I am using a standard domain for the English version `http://website.com` and a subdomain for the French version `http://fr.website.com`

When using the standard `$ meteor deploy`, you can specify the domain you're sending it to. For example, I can keep a French branch and an English branch in the same repository, and then deploy to `$ meteor deploy fr.website.com` when I want to deploy to the French subdomain.

I've properly configured the DNS settings with Godaddy.

The syntax appears to be different with Modulus.io... How do I deploy a different version of the site to a subdomain using Modulus.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your domain in "CUSTOM DOMAINS" at the Project Administration and you also need to set the ROOT_URL environment variable.

Comment: Thank you Mario. I set the "CUSTOM DOMAINS" to "website.com" (obviously referring to the actual website) and I set the ROOT_URL to the "website.onmodulus.net" url. Is there anything else I need to do to get the subdomain working? How do I deploy a different version of the site to a different subdomain?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you need to create another project. I think that in Modulus.io, 1 project == 1 app.

Comment: You are correct. The way to do it is to create a second project, then, when you deploy, rather than just giving you a "yes or no", it gives you the option to deploy to project 1 or project 2.